# What is the recommended average output current of SN74HC14 inverter?

Tags: inverter, cmos

By reading the specs of the SN74HC14 inverter, I'm unable to understand what is the output current limits **per gate** and **for the whole inverter**.

I have read into many websites where they use it for different purposes, but nowhere the two values are explicitly given. I was unable to find that in many different versions of the datasheet of the inverter. Here (https://www.ti.com/product/SN74HC14) is the website of TI. It states 4mA, but its not written per gate or for the whole inverter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Absolute Maximum" limits are clearly stated:

[image]

So if all 6 outputs are all sinking (or all sourcing) current, the **absolute maximum** would be 8.3mA each.

It's good practice to stay *well away* from absolute maximum limits so you might want to keep to a fraction or small fraction of that number depending on how much you care about reliability and lifespan (and to some extent how benign the environment is). Electromigration is one potential failure mode (the narrow aluminum conductors on the chip can have extreme current densities - a million or ten million amperes per cm^2 - even at such modest external currents).

Please note that the 74HC14 is a *logic chip* and is primarily specified to drive other logic chips. Using it to drive LEDs, coils, or whatever is a bit off-label. That doesn't mean it won't work well within its limitations, but if you want guarantees a driver chip may be a better choice.

Comment: I understand that the field "continuous current through VCC or GND" gives the answer that the values are for the whole inverter, not per gate.

Comment: For the whole hex inverter package, yes. As always with datasheets, the effective limit is  the more restrictive of all the applicable limits.

Comment: Just noting that the question was for the recommended (safe to use in a long term, with different temperatures) average output current, not the absolute one, but I guess when there is no explicit value then one have to use some "reasonable" part of the absolute limit. If the stated value by TI of 4mA is "reasonable" per gate that means that 8mA is "proportionally reasonable" per chip. Right?

Comment: 4mA represents an output current at which the output voltage drop is guaranteed. I would *not* relate that directly to the 'safe' value (though it is certainly safe). The choice of 4mA is probably historically related to driving LSTTL inputs and represents a fan-out of 10 over a certain temperature range.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave some 20% margin from the absolute maximum for max current, you ought to be OK **e.g. 20 mA for two ports.** but have 1V drop for each.

**Abs max spec:**

- Per output ±25    mA over free convection air or
- Continuous current through VCC, GND     ±50 mA

The 4mA rated current is for a specified voltage threshold for good noise margins and that ratio V/I defines the Ron of the FET for typ and worst case at 25'C  The Ron does rise with junction temp.  At 5V the 74HC family is typically 50 ohms = Rout +/- 33% (AFAI recall) at 25'C.

You can also run them in tandem to boost gate current or use 3.3V 74ALC with 25 Ohm logic to reduce power and increase current.

Or 74LVC2 family can drive 32 mA with rated voltage thresholds so they are much lower Rout or Ron or RdsOn resistance.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that +-25mA is per gate (Io) and +-50mA is for the whole inverter. If I use two of the gates in tandem, I think for the time one gate is LOW and the other is HIGH (assuming that time is not zero) the positive and the negative are actually shorted.

Comment: Or a driver chip.  Or a transistor.